# Problems with Perl Mechanize and Proxies

Tags: perl, proxy, mechanize

I've been frustrating myself with this for way too many hours.  I think this should be simple but I obviously have something fundamental wrong.  I've read:

I've read the cpan docs for :
WWW-Mechanize/lib/WWW/Mechanize/FAQ.pod
libwww-perl-5.837/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm

And every bit of sample code or article I could find on Google.

This is my first time looking for help on Stack Overflow.  Thanks for your help in advance.  Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use WWW::Mechanize;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new ( agent => "Mozilla/5.0" );

my $proxy = 'http://fetch4.me';

$mech->no_proxy('localhost');
$mech->proxy(['http', 'https', 'gopher'], $proxy) or die $!;
$mech->get('http://www.google.com');

print $mech->uri(),"\n";
print $mech->content(),"\n";
print $mech->text(),"\n";
print $mech->status(),"\n";
```

Here is the output:

```
http://www.google.com
<html>Apache is functioning normally</html>

Apache is functioning normally
200
```

I'm running out of ideas here.  Does this code work for you? Does it produce the same results? What's wrong with it? >.<

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be in the server fetch4.me. Try, for instance, instead

my $proxy = 'http://124.207.162.87:80';

Comment: Thank you very much for your input.  It appears to be working properly now.  It looks like I had everything right except fetch4.me would never work. I tested other proxies they all behaved the same way as fetch4me.  I found an alternate list of proxies that will work though.  Thank you for helping me resolve this issue I was getting really frustrated.  Kinda feel silly now should have done more tests.  I tried to rate your answer but I don't have enough rep =\

Answer (score 1):

Does saying:

```
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new ( agent => "Mozilla/5.0", noproxy => 1 );
```

help?

The doc implies you need to do that to avoid an implicit call to LWP's env_proxy.

Comment: Thank you for your reply ysth.  I made the modification as you pointed out and it seems to have no influence on output.  Oddly enough if I substitute a domain I know is not up or good instead of www.google.com I get the same output.  So it seems like even though the $mech->uri() indicates I'm getting the content() of Google its really coming from the proxy.

Comment: @PSCO: I suggest taking Mech out of the equation; see if you can get proxying working with just LWP::UserAgent first.

Comment: I'll give that a shot and report back.